# Encrypt content of a file in java without requiring to manually specify the encryption key

Tags: java, encryption

I am developing a tool in java (sort of like an SDK) which stores sensitive configuration (like api key) in a file. I saw about **ProtectedData class of C# to acess DPAPI in windows**, is there any java alternative to encrypt the contents of config file without requiring to manually provide a key which works on windows, linux and mac environment ?

Sorry if this question does not belong here.

Comment: Sorry, but dont got "sorry if asking off topic question". Instead: revisit the [help] to learn how/what to ask here. In essence, you are asking for a library/tool to get something done, and such questions are explicitly off topic in this community.

Comment: Oh, I realize my mistake. Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 2):

For encryption you basically need a key. It can be provided by a user, stored in a configuration file or provided by some secured hardware.

> I saw about ProtectedData class of C# to acess DPAPI in windows

The DPAPI is basically windows only and as well there is a [JNI wrapper](http://jdpapi.sourceforge.net/index.html) around the DPAPI you could use

> which works on windows, linux and mac environment

DPAPI is part of the Windows API, but under the hood it all interact with a [TPM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module) which should be available on every current hardware.

Java is designed to be platform independent, so you have no way to interact with the hardware out-of-box (any platform specific calls), but there are *JNI wrappers*, such as [TMP/J](http://projects.csail.mit.edu/tc/tpmj/). I'm not sure how current is the project and if it's still working.

As an alternative, there are other hardware modules, e.g. [YubiHSM](https://developers.yubico.com/YubiHSM2/) or you can use a crypto smartcard. In every case the encrypted key will be bound to the hardware with all the consequences.